# Python datetime and finding birthyear

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to make small program where I can find the birth year, given the age,

```
import datetime
x=raw_input("your age is?")
y=datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y")
print y-x
```

However, this is not working because of the format of the output.

Answer (score 2):

The most straightforward way to get this should be

```
y = datetime.datetime.now().year
```

Answer (score 0):

`strftime(..)` returns a string. You need to convert into an `int`.

```
y = int(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y"))
```

Comment: And you still get the wrong result most of the time. Especially when run this late in the year.

Comment: ... why not `datetime.datetime.now().year`?

Comment: @qwrrty that should be an answer, I think, not a comment

Comment: I thought maybe there actually was a reason :-)

Comment: @qwrrty Thats actually a cleaner way. You have my +1! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your input and current year need to be integers.

```
from datetime import datetime

x = int(raw_input("What is your age? "))  # Get user's age
y = datetime.now().year                   # Get current year

print("Your birth year: {}".format(y-x))  # Print difference
```

Comment: If tomorrow my birthday then the code would return different birth year.